# Unity gun flipping

Tags: visual-studio

I'm making a top down shooter game and when I point my gun backwards, it is upside down. Here's my player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Camera cam;
Vector2 movement;
Vector2 mousePos;
public GameObject crossHair;
public SpriteRenderer sr;



void Start() {
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    crossHair.transform.position = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(movement.x, movement.y) * moveSpeed;

    Vector3 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
    lookDir.Normalize();
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rb.rotation = angle;

    if (transform.position.y >= 6.4f) {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 6.4f);
    }
    if (transform.position.y <= -6.4f) {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, -6.4f);
    }
    if (transform.position.x >= 11.9) {
        transform.position = new Vector2(11.9f, transform.position.y);
    }
    if (transform.position.x <= -11.9) {
        transform.position = new Vector2(-11.9f, transform.position.y);
    }
    float z = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
    if (z > 0 && z < 180 && !sr.flipX)
        sr.flipX = true;
    else if (z < 360 && z > 180 && sr.flipX)
        sr.flipX = false;
}

void Flip(){
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.y *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

}

[image: My gun is upside down]

I've searched a lot but I couldn't make it work. I tried with spriteRenderer but it doesn't work either. I really need help.(Btw my player rotates with the player)

Comment: did you try switching Flip on the x or z axis?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your system is just rotating the object without a second though for what direction it's facing. I imagine if you put an arrow or triangle pointing in the direction you like instead of a gun, it would look just fine.

So what I would do is the following:

```
if (the rotation is backwards)
   render the sprite flipped vertically
else
   render the sprite normally
```

Comment: I dont really understand what do you mean about the rotation is backwards. Can you explain to me ?

Comment: By if rotation is backwards, I mean checking your rotation to see if it's in the bounds of what makes your gun seem like it's upside down.

In your case, I would guess that that would be checking if the player is facing left.